# save all my work on sql in a file?

Tags: sql, bash, file

Actually , i am working on Mysql in linux terminal .

i want a way or a command to save all the queries i write and their outputs in a file .

well, write every query and redirect it to a file is very hard and useless !

if there is any bash script or command it will be helpfull .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just founded that there is an sql command to save query and output in a file ;

```
mysql> tee filename ;
```

example :

```
mysql> tee tmp/output.out;
..logging to file 'tmp/output.out'
```

now : every query and his output will be saved in a  output.out file.

**note : " remember to write file name without quotes"**

Answer (score 3):

yes , tee command can be use for this purpose .

while logging into mysql you can make this redirection like

mysql -u username -pPassword | tee -a outputfilename

your whole session will be stored in the file

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit advanced, but I've just started playing with org-babel, and it's pretty great for SQL.

Set up org-babel in your `init.el`:

```
(org-babel-do-load-languages 'org-babel-load-languages
                             '((sql . t)))
(setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil
      org-src-fontify-natively t
      org-src-tab-acts-natively t)
```

And create an org-mode buffer.  You can just run `M-x org-mode` in `*scratch*` if you want.

Then write your SQL:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sql :engine "mysql" :dbhost "db.example.com" :dbuser "jqhacker" :dbpassword "passw0rd" :database "the_db"
show tables
select * from the_table limit 10
#+END_SRC
```

Evaluate it by putting the cursor in the SQL block and type `C-c C-c`.  The results show up in the buffer.  You can write as many source blocks as you like, and evaluate them in any order.

There's a lot more to org-babel: http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-sql.html